# google maps how to generate url with more than 2 latitude longitudes

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am new to Google maps path drawing in Android.

in my project I need to send last five latitude ,longitudes information as a URL and send SMS to my friends or share on Facebook
for that I need URL as a message to send SMS.
I am searching to form URL with last five longitudes and latitudes.

Answer (score 0):

All of the parameters available as parts of the url are available here: http://moz.com/ugc/everything-you-never-wanted-to-know-about-google-maps-parameters.

This would seem to suggest that you cannot use multiple lon/lat pairs within the url request unless you are looking to plot a route using the directionsService.